# Can I host the database on Always on Availability group in SQL Server 2012 in desktop application created in .net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2012

I am creating a desktop application in C#. The application needs to connect to a SQL Server database. Connection string contains the information of server and database.

Can I host the database on an Always on Availability group in SQL Server 2012? Because AlwaysOn availability group change the database as per availability. Will connection string also changed in this case?

Answer (score 1):

No, the AG will have it's own connection string.

For example, you might have 2 servers as:

- Site1-Service-DB.company.com
- Site2-Service-DB.company.com

But then you would have:

- AG-Service-DB.company.com

You're app would connect to "AG-Service-DB.company.com" instead of any of the instances at individual sites.

*Obvious security concerns about connection strings in desktop apps apply.*